# Error when trying to ingest a file in Geomesa

Tags: geomesa

I installed and configured Geomesa using Docker containers. The versions I used for the various applications are:

- Geomesa 4.0.1
- Hadoop 2.10.2
- Apache Accumulo 2.0.1
- Apache Zookeepeer 3.7.1

To ingest a file I use the following command

```
geomesa-accumulo ingest --force -i accumulo -z zookeeper -u username -p myPassword -c myCatalog -f myFeature  /path/to/shapefile
```

Most shapefile, GeoJSON, csv format files seem to be ingested correctly. But when I try to ingest shapefile with many features, it gives the following error.

```
2023-07-20 14:20:13,122 ERROR [org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest] Fatal error running local ingest worker on /data/hdfs/file_geomesa/file.shp
java.io.IOException: Error occurred trying to reproject data
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:723)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert.shp.ShapefileConverter.parse(ShapefileConverter.scala:74)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.convert2.AbstractConverter.process(AbstractConverter.scala:151)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$4(LocalConverterIngest.scala:172)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$4$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:168)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach(IterableOnce.scala:575)
        at scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.foreach$(IterableOnce.scala:573)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.collection.CloseableIterator$CloseableSingleIterator.foreach(CloseableIterator.scala:85)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$3(LocalConverterIngest.scala:168)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$3$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:167)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.package$WithClose$.apply(package.scala:64)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$2(LocalConverterIngest.scala:167)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.$anonfun$run$2$adapted(LocalConverterIngest.scala:166)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.io.CloseablePool$CommonsPoolPool.borrow(CloseablePool.scala:68)
        at org.locationtech.geomesa.tools.ingest.LocalConverterIngest$LocalIngestWorker.run(LocalConverterIngest.scala:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Nothing to be reprojected! (check before using wrapper)
        at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureReader.<init>(ReprojectFeatureReader.java:152)
        at org.geotools.data.crs.ReprojectFeatureReader.<init>(ReprojectFeatureReader.java:117)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:719)
        ... 19 more
```

I tried editing the shapefile in several ways. I have tried converting it to other formats, such as GeoJSON and csv, through QGIS and with Python libraries. I have tried reducing the number of columns and/or rows. Almost all of the transformations I did, while making the error change sometimes, still resulted in the ingestion failing.
Intuitively I would say that the problem lies in the file, but all the other tools open and process it without any problems.
Is there any configuration of Geomesa that I could try to modify to solve the problem?